# divide a number in k parts such that GCD of the part is maximum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

You have been given a number $N$. You have to divide it in exactly $k$ parts such that the gcd of the $k$ parts is maximal.

Comment: What do you want? An algorithm? Some bounds on the GCD? It is also useful to post what you have thought about so far : it helps others on the site.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider writing the question in slightly more mathematical form, if possible.

Comment: @Tanukumar **HINT:** The GCD of a bunch of numbers can never be bigger than the smallest of the numbers.